# How can I place a log in link over this section in the top right corner without shifting the entire content

Tags: html, css

This is my first html/css project. I tried to use nav and ul tags to put a Log in option on the top right corner over the image. When I do it shifts everything from the middle. I did google before posting but I haven't been successful. I am just wanting to know if I have to float it over or mess with the padding and margins? Here is the html markup`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>AudioPhile</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <section class="intro">
        <div class="inner">
            <div class="content">
                <h1>Audio<img class="logo" src="https://image.ibb.co/n2A7gb/bar_diagram.png" alt=" folder with white music bars">Phile</h1>
                <p>Create. Play. Share music anywhere, on any device with unlimited free storage.</p>
                <input class="signup" type="email" id="myEmail" value="Type Your Email Here">
                <a class="btn-1" href="#">Get Started</a>
                <footer class="credits">&copy; Natalie Pickrom</footer>
                    </div>
            </div>  
    </section>
</body>
</html>`



    The CSS:`@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Archivo+Narrow|Nunito:200');

    html, body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
    }

    .intro {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        margin: auto;
         background:linear-gradient(0deg,rgba(64,64,64,0.8),rgba(64,64,64,0.8)),url(https://preview.ibb.co/jZbkZw/james_stamler_153487.jpg) no-repeat 95% 95% ;
        background-size: cover;
        display: table;
        top:0;
        }

    .intro .inner  {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        width: 100%
        max-width: none;    
    }

    .content {
        max-width:500px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align:center;
    }

    .content h1 {
        font-family: "Archivo Narrow", Helvetica, sans-serif ;
        color: #F9F3F4;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 300px #000;
        font-size: 6em;
        padding:0px;
        margin:0px;

    }

    .content p {
        font-family: Nunito, "Open Sans", sans-serif;
        font-size: 1.253em;
        color:#F9F3F4;
        Paddding: 0px;
        margin-top: 0px;

    }

    .signup {
        border: 0px;
        font-family: Nunito, "Open Sans", sans-serif;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
        color: rgba(128,128,128,0.7) ;
        padding: 5px;
        width: 67%;

    }

    .btn-1 {
        border-radius:0px;
        background-color: #008CBA;
        font-family: Nunito, "Open Sans", sans-serif;
        color:#F9F3F4;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        padding: 3px 10px 4px;
        width:50%;  
    }

    .credits {
        font-family: Nunito, "Open Sans", sans-serif;
        color:#F9F3F4;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 10px;

    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
        .content h1 {
            font-size:4em;
        }
        .btn-1 {
            padding: 2px 10px 3px;
            width: 25%;

        }

    p {
        font-size: .5em;
    }

    }
    `
```

Here is the JSfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/1ysegrd6/

Here is what I want to achieve. I want log in where they have home subscribe
[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: Can you provide jsfiddle or a screen of your website and what you exactly want to achieve ?

Comment: I updated the post with the following info. Thank you

Comment: Could probably just use position: absolute